# How do I programmatically setup the layer of an NSView

Tags: cocoa, calayer

What is the right way to do this?  Here is what I am trying.  But display is never called on dotLayer:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    DotLayer *dotLayer = [[DotLayer alloc]init ];
    dotLayer.frame= CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
    dotLayer.nDots = 4;
    NSView *contentView = window.contentView;
    CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc]init];
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);
    contentView.layer = layer;
    [layer addSublayer:dotLayer];
    [dotLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

DotLayer is a CALayer subclass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you forget to setWantsLayer maybe?

```
contentView.wantsLayer = true
```

That is often the problem!

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Notably, in Swift though, it's `contentView.wantsLayer = true`